# Android can't play H264/AAC video

Tags: android, ios, video, mp4, h.264

We are recording video files in iOS application and want them to be played on iOS/Android/Web. So we chose H264/AAC in MP4 container for that.
However, during different settings, iOS H264 videos are not played on Android devices (LG D335/Galaxy S4).
How we play videos? Simple way to test is to download the video from the direct link and then open it in Downloads on Android device. 
For any iOS H264 video we receive "Can't play this file"/"Sorry, this video cannot be played"

Mediainfo of the video files are below.

Wondering, **why these video files cannot be played on Android, while it's H264/AAC and Baseline profile?**

Thank you.

*MediaInfo outputs*

*iOS 1280x720:*

```
General
Complete name                            : /Users/a/Desktop/ios_1280.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : QuickTime
Codec ID                                 : qt  
File size                                : 6.46 MiB
Duration                                 : 1s 220ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 44.5 Mbps
Recorded date                            : 2015-08-20T20:33:20+0300
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-08-20 17:33:20
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-08-20 17:33:22
Writing application                      : 7.1.2
Writing library                          : Apple QuickTime
Model                                    : iPhone 4
Make                                     : Apple
com.apple.quicktime.make                 : Apple
com.apple.quicktime.creationdate         : 2015-08-20T20:33:20+0300
com.apple.quicktime.software             : 7.1.2
com.apple.quicktime.model                : iPhone 4

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : N=1
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1s 220ms
Source duration                          : 1s 235ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 43.8 Mbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Rotation                                 : 90°
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 29.970 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 28.571 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 1.587
Stream size                              : 6.45 MiB (100%)
Source stream size                       : 6.45 MiB (100%)
Title                                    : Core Media Video
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-08-20 17:33:20
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-08-20 17:33:22
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 1s 220ms
Source duration                          : 1s 254ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 64.0 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel positions                        : Front: C
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 9.61 KiB (0%)
Source stream size                       : 9.78 KiB (0%)
Title                                    : Core Media Audio
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-08-20 17:33:20
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-08-20 17:33:22
```

*iOS 640x480:*

```
General
Complete name                            : /Users/a/Desktop/ios_640.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : QuickTime
Codec ID                                 : qt  
File size                                : 349 KiB
Duration                                 : 1s 133ms
Overall bit rate                         : 2 527 Kbps
Recorded date                            : 2015-08-18T17:46:22+0300
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-08-18 14:46:22
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-08-18 14:46:23
Writing application                      : 8.4.1
Writing library                          : Apple QuickTime
Model                                    : iPhone 5s
Make                                     : Apple
com.apple.quicktime.creationdate         : 2015-08-18T17:46:22+0300
com.apple.quicktime.model                : iPhone 5s
com.apple.quicktime.software             : 8.4.1
com.apple.quicktime.make                 : Apple

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L3
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 1s 133ms
Bit rate                                 : 2 434 Kbps
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Rotation                                 : 90°
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 25.588 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 24.000 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 30.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.310
Stream size                              : 337 KiB (96%)
Title                                    : Core Media Video
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-08-18 14:46:22
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-08-18 14:46:23
Color range                              : Limited
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.601

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 1s 133ms
Source duration                          : 1s 184ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 58.7 Kbps
Nominal bit rate                         : 64.0 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Channel positions                        : Front: C
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 8.11 KiB (2%)
Source stream size                       : 8.44 KiB (2%)
Title                                    : Core Media Audio
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-08-18 14:46:22
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-08-18 14:46:23
```

*Android:*

```
General
Complete name                            : /Users/a/Desktop/android.mp4
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID                                 : mp42
File size                                : 2.56 MiB
Duration                                 : 3s 546ms
Overall bit rate                         : 6 051 Kbps
Performer                                : LGE
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-08-18 18:34:11
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-08-18 18:34:11

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Baseline@L4
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 3s 434ms
Bit rate                                 : 6 084 Kbps
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Rotation                                 : 90°
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 30.000 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 29.900 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 30.030 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.660
Stream size                              : 2.49 MiB (97%)
Title                                    : VideoHandle
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-08-18 18:34:11
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-08-18 18:34:11
mdhd_Duration                            : 3434

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 3s 546ms
Duration_FirstFrame                      : 26ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 155 Kbps
Nominal bit rate                         : 12.2 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 67.0 KiB (3%)
Title                                    : SoundHandle
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2015-08-18 18:34:11
Tagged date                              : UTC 2015-08-18 18:34:11
```

Comment: Can you post the Android versions for the two devices? The files have a different MP4 `ftyp`: `qt` vs `mp42`. A player should be able to play both so maybe there was some bug in a prior version which was patched.

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S4 is 4.4.4, LG is 5.0.3

Comment: Another weird thing is the bitrate for the HD sample. `43.8 Mbps` is huge for HD (the reason it jumped to level `4.1` instead of `3.1`). In that sample's case this could be a factor.

Comment: Level 3.0 is also not played, though (

Comment: One idea is to see if it plays in the VLC app (not the beta). You can also enable a debug log in it.

Comment: VLC for android or just desktop app? Thank you for advice

Comment: The Android app, see if it reports something wrong.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope, we just transcoded video to the format that is playable on Android and iOS.

Comment: And what would “the format that is playable on Android and iOS” be?

Comment: Depends on your audience. Most probably, h264 baseline or main. Don't take it for granted, check what devices and OS versions users run and go from there